# JCE stopped working with secure urls (https) due to mixed content

Tags: https, tinymce, joomla3.0, joomla-content-editor

I am using Joomla 3.6.5 and JCE 2.6.11.

JCE was working fine before, but after converting site URLs to secure (https), JCE stopped working and it is showing "mixed content" errors as all of its js and css loading is with http urls.

Before I had an older version of JCE and in that version the same thing happened.

I had resolved the "mixed content" errors in the older version, but some tools above the editor were not displaying.

So I have decided to upgrade JCE editor, and the now upgraded condition is the same as before:

[image]

Please help me solve this JCE issue with https urls.

Comment: Please always post your Joomla questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

I manually changed the required js baseURI from "http://" to "https://" in the file:

**/components/com_jce/editor/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js**